# Dekstop PC or Server as a WebServer

Tags: php, webserver, server

i am new in this material so i have 2 questions to ask in this 1 post

first of all, i am a PHP developer who wants to host my application into my own PC

(my application is something like social media assuming will have many users)

(i dont want to use any Public WebHosting / VPS , considering cost and security of my data)

and i decided to make my own webserver for my Start-Up Company

but the very problem here is the cost to buy a Server is too expensive if we compare to Desktop PC

**and my question no 1 is**

**For a WebServer based on PHP (Apache) which used Sql Server as a Database , can i just use Desktop PC instead of using Server?**

(considering it will online 24hours / day and processing big amount of request. Assuming i have many users online at the same time)

If let's say i bought 1000$ Desktop PC  which i maximize the money at Processor, Memory and Storage

will it worth more than if i bought 1000$ Server which i maximize the money at Processor, Memory and Storage also

**question no 2 is**

**if i must use Server instead of Desktop PC as my Webserver, i will use Windows Server as my OS,
but if i can use a desktop PC , can i use Windows 7 Professional instead of using Windows Server?**

because some website told me that Windows 7 Professional is not as powerful as Windows Server For a Normal Server (but i dont know about WebServer)

and i dont really know what's the disadvantage if i use Windows 7 Professional instead of using Windows Server as OS for this PHP application

Comment: 1) yes 2) yes you can use win7 or windows server xxx but i recommend you to use unix as os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address your first question :

The main issue with a PC as a server is availablity and security.

Servers are secured and configured in a way that will prevent most issues that you would normally wouldn't think about, like disabling eval, disabling exec, disabling file_get_contents on default, and many other things, hosting companies provide support and assistance on a wide variety of topics.
(Automatic backups of sql, machine users and files also).

the 2nd issue is that if your house loses power, your website is down. if your hd crashes, it takes hours and hours to replace, reinstall, reconfigure and re-deploy your website.

Don't expect your new app to be the next LinkedIN or Twitter or facebook when it comes to traffic and usage, Just start with a small hosting company for the cost of a few $ a year(you can get really cheap hosting, but you get what you pay for) and upgrade accordingly. 
With 1000$ you can buy really good hosting with superb stats for quite a long time.

My suggestion is start with a web hosting, and grow slowly, most hosting companies will allow you to upgrade.

You can use your local machine as a developer environment, but the actual deployment should be done on a server.

Comment: **Servers are secured and configured in a way that will prevent most issues that you would normally wouldn't think about, like disabling eval, disabling exec..** that is not right, when you compile php you can set these settings it is not depending on os or hardware!

Comment: @donald123 that's correct, However as the OP stated that he's new to this matter, I doubt he knows, or wants to pay someone, to configure his system. Note I also did not state that it's hardware or software related. It's just a configuration that's done for you.

Comment: @Patrick firstly i want to thanks for your answer, that's very useful for me. Can i ask you one more thing, let's say if i buy a Servers, should i also configured all of that? or is the Servers that i just bought already been configured to disable eval, and any other security related things?

Comment: Well like stated, That's more of a software configuration than hardware, (the way you compile PHP), Howeve. if you rent a server from a hosting company, normally these things are already in place.  However, if you rent a dedicated server, sometimes those come unconfigured, however they also cost alot more and are normally intended for people who understand fully what they're doing. 
In short, Going with an "out of the box" shared hosting will probably be more than enough, until you learn the ropes and understand the limitations. then you can always move and upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is the internet bandwith. At data centers the bandwith is usually much better than at home PC. 
The second question - the 'white' IP address, that can be accessible from everywhere. Not all internet service providers provide this service.

So, i think you can give a try, if you have good ISP provider. 
Also i think you can use linux instead of windows, if your project is a PHP based site.
What do you use as sql database? MySQL, PostGreSQL, MariaDB or Microsoft SQL server?
I think Windows is only needed, if you want to use Microsoft SQL. In all other cases Linux can be easier to use and cheaper alternative.